# vb.net InitializeComponent() is not declared

Tags: vb.net, initializecomponent

I want to use InitializeComponent() when I create a custom control (to be sure everthing is initialized before I use it), but the compiler says it's not declared. But my Designer.vb contains a sub:

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
```

with all new instances I created.

Why can't I call that?

edit this is how I call InitizialeComponent:

```
Public Class CustomControlsTextBox : Inherits TextBox
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    InitizialeComponent() 'this function is not declared
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Private Sub` means it is not accessible from outside the class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to call it from elsewhere? (note that it's `Private`)  YOu should rely on the constructors.

Comment: thanks, I think that's not the problem. Before I asked here I also tried it with public sub. May someone could post an example of he/she would use that sub :)

Comment: @SLaks: MyBase.new() should be enough or?

Answer (score 2):

InitializeComponent() is private, and can only be called from inside that class. It is called by default by the usercontrol constructor, like this:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

Note that you will only have to call InitializeComponent() yourself if you overload the constructor. Default constructor does it by itself.

Comment: "Note that you will only have to call InitializeComponent() yourself if you overload the constructor. Default constructor does it by itself." This is a very useful information, thank you! I've updatet my question and posted the code, how I use it.

Comment: that means, I don't have to call it in my example. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @MaBi mybase.new is not usually necesary, except in special circunstances (i.e. the constructor of the control you are inheriting for requires a parameter). InitializeComponent() is not necesary unless you need to do something inside the constructor (other than calling InitializeComponent()). In the your example, since you don't do any of those things, you do not need to even overload  the constructor. You could delete it if you wish. Only If you do add something to the constructor, you will need  to call InitializeComponent().

Comment: k, thanks. But nevertheless it's strange that Compiler throws that error if I do.

Answer (score 0):

You should not depend on your Designer.vb's InitializeComponent. Rather, create a new constructor in your `Form1` which will call InitializeComponent()

For example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        'Type all your code here! This code will be executed before the "FormLoad" if you call your new form
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now whenever we use the following code:

```
Dim NewFrm1 As New Form1
```

The `New` constructor in Form1 will be called.